# How to automate usage of a web-based application

Tags: open-source, automation, simulation

I am looking for a way to simulate use of an application with time interval.

What i means is:
There are 5 modules in the app.
I want to display it on a screen and automate switching from module to module so that  it occurs every 15 minutes as if i was doing it myself manually.

Is there any software that can help me with that, or do i have to write a 'robot' for that myself?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want [Selenium](https://www.seleniumhq.org/)

> Selenium automates browsers. That's it! What you do with that power is entirely up to you. Primarily, it is for automating web applications for testing purposes, but is certainly not limited to just that. Boring web-based administration tasks can (and should!) be automated as well.
>
> Selenium has the support of some of the largest browser vendors who have taken (or are taking) steps to make Selenium a native part of their browser. It is also the core technology in countless other browser automation tools, APIs and frameworks.

Comment: Thank you mate!,
If anyone else would be interesed, i am happy to announce that there is a similar topic which i haven't found earlier:
https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/14298/real-user-web-browsing-simulation

Comment: Glad to have been of help. If you are happy with the answer, please accept it by clicking on the tick mark. Doing so will help others who read the question in future. Good luck ;)